# PayPal Transaction History API Cache Refresh

Tags: paypal

I want to know when the transaction API cache will be refreshed so that i can make proper adjustments to the time frame.

I want to fetch the transactions from PayPal within the last hour and do reconciliation process to make sure the data in my db is the same with PayPal.

I checked out an order using PayPal. The order payment was successful and appears in business dashboard activity. But it doesn't appear in the API response and after reading some documentation, I found that there's a last_refreshed_datetime in the response payload.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/
List transactions => response payload => last_refreshed_datetime

I was expecting an updated data but the data was cached and was not updated even after i checkout a new order successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking if you are using the transaction search API, you are using the wrong tool for the job.

In general, the correct tool is the immediate capture API response. With a [standard PayPal checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), no transaction is created until you execute a capture API call, and that API call gives an immediate notification of success or failure, including the resulting transaction ID.

For some rarer use cases, [webhooks event notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/) can be useful, in particular PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED for subscription payments that occur on a schedule, or when integrating third party [alternate payment methods](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/apm/) that might possibly complete without an immediate API response.